# <meta name="viewport" breaks vh/svh of sections in single page website in mobile view(viewed on chrome dev mode)

Tags: html, css

I wrote the single page website, there is sticky navigation bar including z-index: 10(to be always
above), and 4 sections,

```
section {
height: 100vh;
height: 100svh;
}
```

forgot to include in the HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in my HTML and each section took almost the whole viewport.

When I've started to adapt the css file and html I added the `<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">` and now the sections stretched, no more 1 section per 100vh.

When I delete `section{height:100vh height: 100svh}` it breaks desktop but looks somewhat better on mobile.
Here is my body css:

```
body {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
  max-width: 80rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5em 1em 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
}
```

I tried to disable some css code, there's no heigh settings on individual sections.
No JS.

Comment: Instead of height in the viewport, have you tried width instead?

Comment: @imvain2, I did, originally it was width.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: pink;
}
section {
  height: calc(100dvh - 30px);
}
.container {
  max-height: 100dvh;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
}
.scroll {
  scroll-margin-top: 30px;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <div>Navbar</div>
    </nav>
    <section class="scroll" style="background-color: #ffe4c4;">Section 1</section>
    <section class="scroll" style="background-color: #c7ffc4;">Section 2</section>
    <section class="scroll" style="background-color: #c4edff;">Section 3</section>
    <section class="scroll" style="background-color: #e9c4ff;">Section 4</section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Feel free to remove the *scroll* parts if you don't need them. I added them just for fun ;) 
Not sure this is what you are looking for, but I hope it helps.